# Ho to add get_relative_date and post_except to this get_latest_post query?

Tags: get-posts

tried different ways to implement without any success, Any help?

```
<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 99, // Number of recent posts thumbnails to display
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish' // Show only the published posts
));
foreach($recent_posts as $post) : ?>
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
            <h4><?php echo $post['post_title'] ?></h4></a>
            <p class="card-text">Happened time ago</p>
            <p class="card-text">... <small><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post['ID']) ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Read more</a></small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `get_relative_date()` isn't a core WordPress function. Is it one you wrote of from your theme or a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U', $post ) )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/human_time_diff/) and [`get_the_excerpt( $post )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) for these two tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your response @swissspidy. So do you think I can replace:

 **Happened time ago** with `<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U', $post ) )?>` and
 **...** with `<?php get_the_excerpt( $post ) ?>` ?

Or I should use `( $post ['ID'])` in both cases?

Comment: Both should work actially.